# iOS binary submission and encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, nsuserdefaults, app-store-connect

I have a question about submitting a binary to iTunes Connect…  You may remember my question about securing NSUserDefaults a few weeks ago, and I found an answer.  I found "NSUserDefaults+MPSecureUserDefaults.h" (that can be found  here: https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults), that basically encrypts user defaults before saving them on the device.  This file imports CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h in the header.  I was going to submit this app in iTunes Connect…

**Have you added or made changes to encryption features since you last uploaded a binary for this product?**

Do I have to check this?  Thanks!

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually using the github code? Did you notice where it says "Please note that this implementation does not use encryption. It is therefore not suitable to store sensitive data"?

Comment: +1 @smparkes is right, I looked at the source and it seems to just be using common CommonCrypto to generate a shared secret and hash/unhash the text. Not secure at all, it just makes it annoying for someone trying to edit it manually, ie if you stored game center scores in your user defaults and you didn't want someone to artificially raise their score.

Comment: @Jack Lawrence - Yeah ... I know what it does, and that is good enough for my purposes.  (Actually, artificially raised scores are exactly what I'm guarding against).  So I don't have to check the encryption box?

Comment: @TheMe There is no encryption going on here so there's no need to check the encryption box.